# How can I always get the simplest solution from Integrate?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, integral-equations

When I evaluate this.

```
Integrate[1/(x (1 + x^4)^(1/4)), x] // FullSimplify
```

In 11.3 I get

> `-(1/(x^4))(1 + x^4)^(3/4) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 5/4, -(1/x^4)]`

At first I thought this meant the integral only has a non-elementary solution, but I foun [`FunctionExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionExpand.html), can put it into elementary form.

In 12.0 I get

> `(ArcTan[(1 + x^4)^(1/4)] - ArcTanh[(1 + x^4)^(1/4)])/2`

I think 12.0's result is better.

I always want the simplest solution. How can I be sure to get it?

Note:

The V12.0 result can be further simplified by substitution:  $t=x^4,x=\sqrt[4]t, dx=\frac{1}{4 t^{3/4}}dt$

Comment: It is not uncommon for Mathematica to return solutions that are not as simple as one might desire.  The only solution is to use `FullSimplify` (possibly with a custom `TransformationFunction`) or `FunctionExpand` to see whether simpler expressions can be obtained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing "misleading" about either result. Both are valid anti-derivatives that differ by a complex constant.

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

expr = 1/(x (1 + x^4)^(1/4));

int = Integrate[expr, x]

(* 1/2 ArcTan[(1 + x^4)^(1/4)] - 1/2 ArcTanh[(1 + x^4)^(1/4)] *)
```

Verifying that `int` is a valid anti-derivative

```
expr == D[int, x] // Simplify

(* True *)
```

However, this is complex for real `x`

```
Table[int, {x, 1/4, 1, 1/4}] // N

(* {-1.5137 + 0.785398 I, -0.824141 + 0.785398 I, -0.432924 + 
  0.785398 I, -0.176308 + 0.785398 I} *)
```

The imaginary constant is

```
Im[int /. x -> 1] // FullSimplify

(* π/4 *)
```

Subtracting off the constant provides a real-valued anti-derivative

```
int2 = int - I*Pi/4

(* -((I π)/4) + 1/2 ArcTan[(1 + x^4)^(1/4)] - 1/2 ArcTanh[(1 + x^4)^(1/4)] *)
```

The result that you give from an earlier Mathematica version has the advantage that it is compact and real-valued for real input

```
int3 = -(1/(x^4)) (1 + x^4)^(3/4) Hypergeometric2F1[1, 1, 5/4, -(1/x^4)];
```

Verifying that `int3` is a valid anti-derivative

```
expr == D[int3, x] // FullSimplify

(* True *)

Limit[#, x -> Infinity] & /@ {int2, int3}

(* {π/4, 0} *)

Plot[{Pi/4, int2, int3}, {x, -5, 5},
 PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Automatic, Automatic},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.8, .3}]]
```

[image]